# How to install .Net framework in windows container

Tags: windows-container

I took  mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/aspnet:3.5 as a base image for my windows container.To my application I want both 4.7 and 3.5 frameworks.I am unable to install 4.7 in my container.Could you please help me.

Comment: What did you try to do to install it? Practice your steps on vanilla server core image and then incorporate it into dockerfile

Comment: I copied .Net Framework 4.7 exe into the container(by using aspnet:3.5 as base image) and ran the exe file using Start-Process  and as well as Invoke-Item Commands.But the framework version is not showing the 4.7.

Comment: Does it work from command line (that is you docker exec into container and do it)

Comment: Can we install both the frameworks in the same windows container ?

Comment: Shall be able to install anything you want as long as it works in windows server core

Comment: I tried to enable the .Net Framework features in windows servercore:1803 image but it is not supporting.